# How to detect that user stops talking when record microphone with AVAudioEngine?

Tags: ios, audio-recording, avaudioengine

I use AVAudioEngine to record user talking, I want to achieve that when the user pauses or stops talking for over X seconds, will play back the sentence just recorded before.

But how can I detect this pause of talking during recording?? Haven't found useful API in AVAudioEngine, any idea to help me?

Answer (score -1):

You can set Timer inside

```
private let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: "en-US"))!    speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
```

})
block. 
At the time of calling `speechRecognizer.recognitionTask` set the start time and after each subsequent request inside timer check the difference between current time with the start time.If the difference is higher than X seconds, do whatever you want.